# Added `export` command in `.bashrc` to update PATH with binary location -- GUI apps don't know about update even though terminal does?

Tags: gnome-terminal, gui, bashrc

I had to add an:

`export PATH="/path/to/my/bin:$PATH"`

to my `bash.rc`, for `progA`'s binary library location. Now, whenever I start a GNOME Terminal instance, I can type `progA` and hit return and the right binary is executed.

However, if I run `progA` through a GUI launched app, my system fumbles and doesn't know where `progA`'s bin is.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.bashrc` file is only processed for *interactive, non-login* shells: probably a better place to set the path would be your `~/.profile`

For maximum portability, you could follow the existing paradigm of the user's `~/bin` directory in `~/.profile` (i.e. avoiding `export`, and testing for the directory's existence): something like

```
if [ -d "/path/to/my/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="/path/to/my/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Since `~/.profile` is only read for login shells, you will need to log out and back in for it to take effect (or at least, start a new login shell e.g. using `su - username`). From there, the new PATH should propagate to all child shells - including the interactive, non-login shells of your gnome terminals.

Answer (score 1):

First, whatever is inside `.bashrc` applies only to `bash` shell. Unless that mysterious GUI-launched app that you refer to also uses `.bashrc` ( for which I don't see any reason whatsoever  ), then it won't know where is your `progA`.  Even the run dialog (which is Alt+F2 if you didn't know ) uses `dash` not `bash` , so `.bashrc` means nothing to it.     That's for one.

Second, If what you want is to have a desktop or launcher shortcut, you need to have a `myAppName.desktop` file with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myAppName
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/the/progA
Terminal=false
Icon=/path/to/some/icon.png
```

Now when you have that and the file is executable, you can double click that `.desktop` file and launch the app (provided that progA has ownership properly set, permissions set and executable bit set ). `Icon=` part is optional, so you could leave it out.